# Tableau 9.3: using a multi-option set as a filter across multiple data sources

Tags: tableau-api

First Post! am kinda feeling the pressure :)

I've created a multiple option filter for my dashboard using a set (with include all members). which is great for my sheets which use that datasource as primary, but when it's the secondary source I've hit a brick wall - I cannot see (or find any reference in searches) how to use the filter. Any calculated dimensions I've seen reference In/Out. Is there a way round this or something I'm missing?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it when it's based on the secondary source in a data-blending scenario. Currently Tableau only allows for it to be applied to the primary. We are hoping this changes in version 10.0.

Comment: Thank you. Fingers Crossed then.